# How to verify a text in logger in Junit

Tags: logging, junit

I have Junit test case which calls a dev method and this method returns a Yaml on execution. I want to verify a text in the yaml which is returned. I'm Not sure how to do it.

public class MyTest extends DevClass {

```
@Test
public void export_File() throws URISyntaxException, IOException, AuthenticationException {


            String output = DevClass.exportFile("Yaml");

            System.out.println(output);
```

Comment: `assertTrue(yaml.contains(expectedText))`? Where is your code?

Comment: This is the Junit class that I wrote

Comment: Post that in your question, not in comments. There is an edit link.

Comment: System.out.printl... it's not a test. In test you should use asserEquals

Comment: I just wanted to look at the yaml output, hence the print. I'll remove it once I assert the output text

Comment: So, what would you want to check on this output? What have you tried? Have you at least read the JUnit documentation? What does this have to do with logging?

Comment: No, haven't read it

Comment: Then read it. It exists for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

1. Parse the Yaml (using Jackson or some other api)
2. Use the Yaml api to extract the value you are expecting
3. Apply JUnit asserts at each step where the result might return null if the subsection or value is missing.